# A word for a question that in fact consist of two more particular questions?

Tags: single-word-requests

The question I have asked is "what is A's bearing on B?". But the question in fact involves two separate questions, it is both about A's positive bearing on B and A's negative bearings on B. What such a question is called? For example what should be put in the following blank space?

> Does A has any bearing on B? The question is ..., involving both the positive and the negative bearings A might have on B.

The words I have come up with so far are **two-sided** and **twofold**. But I am not sure if they are good enough.

Comment: 'Double-edged' or 'double-sided' are used to mean that there are two aspects to consider.

Answer (score 1):

> **Multifaceted**
> [muhl-tee-fas-i-tid, muhl-tahy-]
> /adjective
>
> 2. having many aspects or phases: *a multifaceted problem.*
>
> [Source: Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/multifaceted)